# Cron fatal error 4.7.2 (D6)

Tags: cron, drupal-6

After upgrading my Drupal 6 site (latest version) to Civi 4.7.2 all cronjobs set up in Cpanel are failing. Scheduled jobs are working fine when triggered in Civi but fail when triggered with the Cron url in the browser.

My cron is

```
wget -O /dev/null http://mysiteurl/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=xxx\&pass=xxx\&key=xxx
```

Error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Utils_System_Drupal6::getUsersTableName() in /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Drupal6.php on line 313
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A patch has been accepted for this.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/76eeb935253f42e836a58e1f9d077caaa498c947

Comment: Patch was included in 4.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the drush method? I found it more reliable to use than the cron one, and more performant than over wget too

Comment: Thanks Xavier, but unfortunately I can't instal drush (and haven't learnt how to use it yet). Does anyone know how I can fix the undefined method error?